# Modal dialogbox or form error in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I keep getting this error when I deploy my application in the server machine (Windows 7, IIS 7).
"Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application."

The problem is I dont have any MessageBox call inside the code. What I did is, generated a DLL from PowerBuilder 12 and added the DLL in a .NET website to generate some reports. Any solution to this? Let me know if you need me to provide any other information. I really need help on this.

Heres the stacktrace:

> [InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when
>   the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid
>   operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style
>   to display a notification from a service application.]
>   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(IWin32Window owner, String
>   text, String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon,
>   MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, MessageBoxOptions options,
>   Boolean showHelp) +2661926
>   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(String text) +37
>   c__app_web_main.InitAssembly() +168    APP_WEB.n_app_web_main..ctor()
>   +18    ASP_TEST.getobject.GetData(String queryString) in
>   C:\Projects\ERP\ASP_TEST\ASP_TEST\getobject.aspx.cs:29
>   ASP_TEST.getobject.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Projects\ERP\ASP_TEST\ASP_TEST\getobject.aspx.cs:20
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +35    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +627

**EDIT:**
The problem occurs when I'm initializing the PB generated assembly, its throwing me an exception and trying to warn me with a messagebox. The assembly works fine in my local pc and my colleagues, so there has to be some security setting in IIS which is causing this problem.

Comment: This is a problem induced by PowerBuilder.  It is probably trying to warn you about something but that can't happen.  Don't use it.  http://forums.sybase.com/cgi-bin/webnews.cgi?cmd=item-388&group=sybase.public.powerbuilder.net.assembly

Comment: Well, this works fine when I deploy it in local IIS, also in my colleagues PC (both using Windows 7 and IIS 7)... the problem must have something to do with permission of the account IIS is running under.

Comment: Also, in the link you provided, looks like he has managed to find a solution: http://forums.sybase.com/cgi-bin/webnews.cgi?cmd=item-389&multi=&group=sybase.public.powerbuilder.net.assembly&utoken=40ee.4e7ea1d8.1804289383@temp:0_~2-ae1f07f1a213e89d07e400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by signing the custom DLL generated from PowerBuilder 12 with a key .

Comment: ShutterBug, I'm having this same issue now.  How did you do the signing of the DLL with a key?

Comment: There are several ways, I used PowerBuilder built-in deployment tool.

Comment: Which options did you choose when you were doing this?  Did you mark Delay sign only?  Or did you Mark the assembly with Allow Partially Trusted Caller Attribute?

Comment: I generated a key file from CMD and used that key file to sign the DLL generated from PowerBuilder 12 using PowerBuilder's own deployment utility.

Comment: In our case, we got this message because someone had deleted atl71.dll (one of our deployment dlls for our webservice) off the server.  Once we added this DLL back, we no longer got this error.  It had nothing to do with the actual PB webservice, as it turned out.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you that if you decompile the DLL using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) you'll find references to Message.Box. You could probably recover the source code and remove the offending piece of code.

Comment: Well, even if I remove the MessageBox call from the source, I wont be able to handle the exception thats causing the MessageBox to show until I know whats causing the problem.

Comment: Well, if you have the source, I think you will be able to do that too, no? Have you heard of debuggers and breakpoints before?